# UISearchController's SearchBar gets detached and overlaps TableView if rotated while not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

So I've got a UITableView with a UISearchController.  It loads up fine, then I do my search and select a result, pushing a new view controller to my UINavigationController.

If, while the new VC is onscreen, I rotate my phone, then rotate back, and go back...when I get back to the UITableView, the UISearchBar is nowhere to be seen.  If, to troubleshoot, I hide the UINavigationBar, or if I look at the view hierarchy, I find that it has moved up behind the navigation bar and is being covered.

I've tried all kinds of hackey solutions, like moving the frame of the bar after it finishes loading, with no success. I really need help on this one, I'm stumped.  None of the stuff I've found on google has helped.

Here are screenshots of before, after, and the view heirarchy:
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRJMy.jpg)

Here is all the View-related code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


if (!self.title)
    self.title = @"GLOBAL SEARCH";

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//TESTING
//if I don't have this, the bar detaches from the navigation bar
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
//test


self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                   self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                   self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                   44.0);


self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = kConstantBaseColor;
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = kConstantBaseColor;
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = kConstantLabelColor;

 //set color
 [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:kConstantLabelColor}];


self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
[self.searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = kConstantBaseColor;

 //put purple block above, in case user scrolls up
CGRect bufferFrame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y-300,
                                self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width*2,
                                300);
UIView *purpleBuffer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bufferFrame];
purpleBuffer.backgroundColor = kConstantBaseColor;
[self.tableView addSubview:purpleBuffer];
}


- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

}];  
 }
```

Does anyone have any solutions?  I'm stumped and have been beating my head against it for days.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I describe a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914135/layout-of-uisearchbar-in-uitableview-header-messed-up-after-rotation/39929972#39929972

Comment: My searchbar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571676/uisearchbar-in-uitableview-header-layout-issue-in-ios-14