# UISearchBar Under Navigation Bar after Rotation and Segue

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar as the header on table view inside a navigation controller. The search bar, after completing a 'Show' segue, rotating the device, and returning to the view with the table view, appears underneath the navigation bar. This only occurs when the search bar is active, and when the rotation occurs in the other view controller (the one the table view is in).

How can I either cause the UISearchBar to properly update while rotating the other view, or force the position of the searchBar to update when I return to the view?

Comment: This answer should be of help - [save/restore the search state] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914135/layout-of-uisearchbar-in-uitableview-header-messed-up-after-rotation/39929972#39929972.